# Replace sub-string in a FOR loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd, substring

I want specific String later Path,

```
set PROJECT_FOLDER_PATH=E:\aaa\bbb\cccc
FOR /f %%i IN ('dir /b /s %PROJECT_FOLDER_PATH%\src\*.c') DO echo %%i:bbb\=%
```

Expected Result: `cccc\src\test.c`

but current Result: `E:\aaa\bbb\cccc\src\test.c:bbb\=`

Please, help me

Comment: You could check [this post here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17279114/6707985) and use the information of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15568171/6707985) and combine them to get the result I think you needed. Also I recommend you to read [the tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how this site works.

Comment: Is `test.c` a folder? Is it supposed to be in `PROJECT_FOLDER_PATH`? What is the purpose of the `=`? One way to do this would be to get the name of the parent folder before the `FOR /f`, like this: `FOR %%a in (%PROJECT_FOLDER_PATH%) do SET parent=%%~na`. Then you can use `parent` and a similar method to get the file name from the next FOR, and put them together.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use the replace syntax on a parameter-style variable like `%i`. First store the value to a normal variable using `set`.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set PROJECT_FOLDER_PATH=E:\aaa\bbb\cccc
FOR /f %%i IN ('dir /b /s %PROJECT_FOLDER_PATH%\src\*.c') DO (
    set TMP_PATH=%%i
    echo !TMP_PATH:bbb\=!
)
```

We need [Delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) of variables to set and read the variable in the same loop. Otherwise, the variable in `echo` command would be expanded before entering the loop.