# Get last part of directory in for loop, using cd, and in one line

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, pathname

I mean to obtain the last part of a full directory path, when it comes from `cd`, it is used with `for`, and set all in one line.

When coming from `cd`, the path is something like `C:\a\b\c\d\`.
The trailing backslash complicates things.

[This](https://serverfault.com/a/246874/326962) is ok for one line in the case of a directory with no trailing backslash (i.e., it cannot come from `cd`).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17279910/2707864) is ok for the case of trailing backslash, but not for one line.

The output of

```
> FOR %%a IN (`cd`) DO echo %%~pa
```

is `\a\b\c\d\`
and the output of

```
> FOR %%a IN (`cd`) DO echo %%~na
```

is `` `cd` `` (I expected an empty string here).

I guess I should combine this with a syntax like `set MYDIR1=%MYDIR:~0,-1%` and multiple commands in one line like `command1 && command 2`.
The target one liner would be 
something like

```
FOR %%a IN (`cd`) DO set MYDIR1=%MYDIR:~0,-1% && echo %%~nMYDIR1
```

and perhaps using `tokens` and/or `delims` but I couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve the information for the current folder

```
for %%a in (".") do echo %%~nxa
```

To retrieve the information using a variable with or without an ending backslash

```
for %%a in ("%cd%\.") do echo %%~nxa
```

But note that, in both cases, you don't have a name+extension available for a drive's root folder.

Answer (score 1):

Just another option using a technique discovered on [dostips.com](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=3)

```
set "last=%cd:\=" & set "last=%"
echo %last%
```

Comment: Split string into substrings based on delimiter by [Sponge Belly/dostips.com](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6429)